# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with() in Repository

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

I am trying to follow the tutorial below but for some reason the make method doesn't work in my case. When I try to use it as explained in the tutorial I get the error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()

http://culttt.com/2014/03/17/eloquent-tricks-better-repositories/

```
public function make(array $with = array())
{
  return $this->model->with($with);
}
```

Then I try to use this as follows:

```
public function parents(array $with = array())
{
  $query = $this->make($with);

  return $query->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
}
```

This is slightly different from the code in the tutorial but it shouldn't make a difference. Even when I use the exact same example it breaks with the error above.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but most of that article is BS, so close it, forget it and never look at it again. Better read this one https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/ , though it presents much more complex approach. And the error you're getting says, you're working with `Query\Builder` object instead of `Eloquent\Builder`, so resolve this and you'll be OK.

Comment: Could you point out why the article is BS? I figured out the problem, I simply had a typo in the relationship I was trying to pull in the with() method....

Comment: It's inconsistent, has errors and title is misleading - there is literally no trick for eloquent in there. I know Philip provided many tutorials on his site, I suppose many find them helpful, but this one is bad.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that if you have a typo in the relationship you're trying to pull in this scenario it will give you this error. It's highly confusing.